# Rails Resetting Thumbs_up votes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, voting

What's the easiest way to reset the vote counter to zero when a voting period is ended with the thumbs_up gem?

Say... for example... I want to set a topic that starts Monday at Midnight and ends Sunday at 11:59?

Also what's the quickest way to zero all the votes in MySql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow... Guess I'll be answering this one myself.

To reset the votes (in mysql at least), you just have to go into mysql's client and type in:

```
truncate table [whateverthenameis];
```

As for how to automate this... I haven't the slightest idea.